# How to implement interrupt flags in C, using a Microcontroller?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I have set up a project using a 16-bit Microcontroller called Thunderbird12, similar to the 9s12/Freescale 68HC12 family. It does a few things but mainly turn on an external water pump. Everything works fine except I need to implement an interrupt. I want to be able to stop the motor using an interrupt through a push button.

I have set up the button which sets pin 0 of port P to high when pressed. Using C, I have initialized the hardware and written the code but the flag is not called. Please see code below.

```
// Interrupt function
int interruptFlag;
void interrupt 56 WaterPumpRoutine() {
   if ((PIFP & 0x01) == 0x01) {   // check if pin 0 of port p is high (when button is pressed)
   interruptFlag = 1; // set the flag to 1           
} 

// Main
void main() {

DDRP = 0x00; // set port P as input
PIEP = PIEP | 0x01; // enable interrupts on port P, pin 0
PERP = PERP | 0x01; // enable pull-up/down on port P, pin 0

if ( interruptFlag == 1)
      PORTB = (PORTB & 0x00) // Here I'm turning off all the pins in Port B, which includes the pump.
}
```

If I put this code `PORTB = (PORTB & 0x00)` inside the `WaterPumpRoutine()` function, it works fine, but I need to be able to call the flag anywhere. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the interrupt call works fine..

1. Change the variable `int interruptFlag;` to `volatile int interruptFlag;`. This is to avoid optimizing away the `if` condition in main by the compiler.
2. In `main` you need to reset the `interruptFlag` on some condition. This is program dependent. Maybe you can do it like this.

   ```
   if ( interruptFlag == 1)
   {
         PORTB = (PORTB & 0x00) // Here I'm turning off all the pins in Port B, which includes the pump.
         interruptFlag = 0;
   }
   ```
3. If you are using a push button, you should introduce a debounce mechanism to avoid detecting multiple inputs.
4. You need to add the if condition in main inside a while(1) loop as the interrupt can come at any time.

   ```
   while(1)
   { 
       if(interruptFlag == 1)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just edited the code, still not interrupting when I push the button. I have the other inputs on pull-down resistor. It's funny you mentioned that because I experienced electric noise on other inputs and they were reading on and off erratically before I knew about pull-up and pull down resistor set up, which solved that problem.

Comment: That's what I have. There is a ```while (1)``` loop that contains the entire code and I added the ```if (interruptFlag == 1)``` inside it, at the beginning.

Comment: @asynts It does not recognize it. I get the error: Object is missing declaration specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If u still can't get interrupt to fire , after things that other suggested, you should check if you got global interrupts or interrupt for specific part (GPIO) enabled since in most uc setting GPIO to generate interrupts doesn't enable interrupts

Comment: I'm using port P, which I tested and it's working if I include everything in the function.